# Jython error when trying to import a Python library

Tags: java, python, jython

I have a simple python script that I want to call, the script has a demo pandas DataFrame which I want to return to my Java code.

```
import re
import sys
sys.path.append('D:/JythonProject/venv/Lib/site-packages')
from dateutil.parser import parse
import pandas as pd  # You may need to pip install these libraries
```

The error that it is throwing

```
 import pandas as pd  # You may need to pip install these libraries
SyntaxError: ('no viable alternative at input \'"{dependency}: {e}"\'', ('D:\\Projects\\snowflakeConnector\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\__init__.py', 13, 37, '        missing_dependencies.append(f"{dependency}: {e}")\n'))
```

I know the error is being thrown when trying to import pandas but I don't know why.

Comment: You cannot use pandas in Jython. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/36213908/407651

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jython does not work properly with pandas also for other libraries you have to point out to the venv in the script.