# Calling python having imports from 3rd party modules from Java using jython gives ImportModuleError

Tags: python, java, jython, pythoninterpreter

I am trying to create a maven java project which calls python script that have imports from 3rd party modules like pandas. I have installed Python3 and installed pandas using pip command. I am using vsCode as IDE and has windows 10 OS.

Im attaching the sample code i used.

App.java

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
  interpreter.execfile("./src/main/resources/hello.py");
  PyFunction function = interpreter.get("get_data", PyFunction.class);
  PyObject obj = function.__call__();
  System.out.println(obj);
```

hello.py

```
import pandas as pd

def get_data():
    data = {'name': ['John', 'Emily'],
            'age': [30, 40]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    return df
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.python</groupId>
        <artifactId>jython-standalone</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

The error I am getting is **ImportError: No module named pandas**.
What I am expecting is that the program is not able to find the modules from python lib.

Comment: You cannot use Pandas with Jython: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36213908/407651

Comment: @mzjn The link tells about jython version 2.7.0. Im using 2.7.2. Pandas is not available in 2.7.0 as well?

Comment: It does not matter what the Jython version is. You cannot use Pandas.