# Running Python Script using Java with venv

Tags: python, java, cmd

I am trying to run a python script from inside Java, I cant use Jython since I'm using the module Pandas in my script

Here is the code

```
public class CalculateWarranty {

    private Logger logger = ApplicationLogger.createLogger(CalculateWarranty.class);

    public void calculate(String filename) {
        try {
            String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");
            ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
            String projectPath = Paths.get(userHome, "OneDrive", "Documents", "coding projects", "MediaMarkt", "WarrantyReaderWebApplication", "WarrantyReaderApp").toString();
            String venvPath = "C:\\Users\\sanso\\OneDrive\\Documents\\codingprojects\\MediaMarkt\\WarrantyReaderWebApplication\\WarrantyReaderApp\\venv\\Scripts\\activate";
            String scriptPath = "C:\\Users\\sanso\\OneDrive\\Documents\\codingprojects\\MediaMarkt\\WarrantyReaderWebApplication\\WarrantyReaderApp\\scripts\\calcuscript.py";
            String dataPath = "C:\\Users\\sanso\\OneDrive\\Documents\\codingprojects\\MediaMarkt\\WarrantyReaderWebApplication\\WarrantyReaderApp\\src\\main\\resources\\data\\data.xls";
            String command = scriptPath + " " + dataPath;
            logger.error(command);
            logger.error(venvPath);
            logger.error(scriptPath);
            logger.error(dataPath);

            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe",venvPath);
            Process process = processBuilder.start();

            InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            int character;
            while ((character = bufferedReader.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.print((char) character);
            }

            int exitCode = process.waitFor();
            if (exitCode != 0) {
                System.err.println("The Python script exited with an error.");
            }
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason when I run the method the output gets stuck

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2428]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\sanso\OneDrive\Documents\codingprojects\MediaMarkt\WarrantyReaderWebApplication\WarrantyReaderApp>
```

It does nothing after this.
I have no clue why, I ran the command in a cmd.exe and it worked perfectly fine
I also want to know if there is a better approach for this than using a ProcessBuilder
And also how can I improve my code so I can deploy this onto a Linux running, I know I would need to modify my hard-coded variables but everytime I used Paths, to get my absolute path I had errors

I tried using Jython Realized that doesn't work, and honestly I kept messing around with the paths, I tried changing how I output the results nothing changed, my code gets blocked, I used Intelijj debug and saw that my while loop gets stuck.

Comment: What is `activate`? share the code.

Comment: Why didn't jython work for you? Did you try setting up python as a separate service and calllng whtevr you need by HTTP?

Comment: @aled activate is a file found in the venv directory, as Mofi said it to set the environment variables

Comment: @hd1 Jython won't [work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37473577/14362677) since I'm using pandas in my python script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took @Mofi advice and stopped calling cmd.exe which caused my loop to get stuck.
After that to set the venv for my python script, I used the python script included in the venv directory in my python script instead of trying to call it using the processBuilder

```
exec(open("C:/Users/sanso/OneDrive/Documents/codingprojects/MediaMarkt/WarrantyReaderWebApplication/WarrantyReaderApp/venv/Scripts/activate_this.py").read(), {'__file__': "C:/Users/sanso/OneDrive/Documents/codingprojects/MediaMarkt/WarrantyReaderWebApplication/WarrantyReaderApp/venv/Scripts/activate_this.py"})

import pandas as pd
import argparse
```

Running the exec command first allows me to import pandas without any issue.
Thanks for the help Mofi